# D3: replacing anonymous function with a named one

Tags: javascript, d3.js, anonymous-function

My abbreviated working D3 code with a number tween:

```
  vLabel.transition()
    .tween('text', function() {
            var n = d3.interpolateNumber(0, frames[i].V);
            return function(t) {d3.select(this).text(n(t).toFixed(1)+'%');};
        });
```

Since the same kind of transition will apply to a number of other elements later in a series of stepped animations, I'd like to turn the anonymous function into a named one to be reused. However, my attempt below produces `NaN` instead of a number.

```
function runNumber(start, end, decimal) {
            var n = d3.interpolateNumber(start, end);
            return function(t) {d3.select(this).text(n(t).toFixed(decimal)+'%');};
    }

vLabel.transition()
  .tween('text', runNumber(0, frames[i].V, 1));
```

I've also tried placing `d3.select(this).tween` inside the function and calling the modified function with the `call()` method, but that produced an outright error ("tween is not a function..."). Being brand-new to JS, I suspect the problem has to do with my tenuous grasp of `this`, although I don't know how to go about fixing it.

Comment: I believe the problem is `this` in the context of `runNumber` function. Try passing `this` from the original call to `runNumber`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to have the same behavior as the original code, you need to return a function (that itself returns a function when called) from `runNumber`. This should work (untested):

```
function runNumber(start, end, decimal) {
    return function() {
        var n = d3.interpolateNumber(start, end);
        return function(t) {
            d3.select(this).text(n(t).toFixed(decimal) + '%');
        };
    };
}
```

Comment: Yes, it does work! I thought the point of the anonymous function is to return something (in this case another function), and that my original named function accomplishes the same thing. But no, apparently the new function has to return an anonymous function itself that in turn returns a function. Can you point to an on-line resource that will help me make sense of this? Many thanks.

Comment: I see now. The `runNumber` function in my code is called and return an anonymous function as a parameter for `tween`, whereas what I need as for the parameter is actually a function that return a function *when called*.